# Show modal upon onClick but its not working - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using react.
I want to display the modal from the bottom when I press the btn button.
I want to show the modal from the bottom, like the modal on this site.
https://codepen.io/takapen/pen/jdwwWQ

I created a modal with the same structure as the modal on this site.
However, when I press the button, the modal is not displayed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const Spin = (
    <style>
      {`
      @keyframes SlideUp {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: translateY(-1%);
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateY(-80%);
        }
      }
    `}
    </style>
  );

  const [isCheck, setIsCheck] = useState(false);
  console.log(isCheck);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        class="js-modal__btn"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsCheck(true);
        }}
      >
        btn
      </div>
      <div
        class="js-modal__bg"
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
          position: "fixed",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 10,
          display: "none"
        }}
      ></div>
      <div
        class="js-modal__main"
        style={{
          width: "calc(100% - 32px)",
          height: "80%",
          padding: "16px",
          bottom: "-81%",
          left: "0",
          background: "#fff",
          borderRadius: "4px 4px 0 0",
          position: "fixed",
          zIndex: 11,
          opacity: "0",
          animation: isCheck ? `${Spin} .5s ease-in-out forwards` : undefined
        }}
      >
        <p>コンテンツ</p>

        <p class="js-modal__btn--close">close</p>
        <p class="js-modal__btn--close--fix"></p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Return the style from spin and try again. Like return <style>

Comment: ```  const Spin = () => {
    return (
      <style>
        {`
      @keyframes SlideUp {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: translateY(-1%);
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateY(-80%);
        }
      }
    `}
      </style>
    );
  };

Comment: I returned spin in return, but it did not change.

Comment: You can try passing all the styles inside js-modal__main and render like this.
{isCheck && <div class="js-modal__main">...</div>}

Comment: I enclosed it in isCheck, but it did not show up.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bas-bf3zj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to render your style to the document.

Second, you need to use the correct name for the animation.

So you need to fix those lines:

```
return (
  <>
    // Render your style
    {Spin}
    // Use the keyframe's name
    animation: isCheck ? `SlideUp .5s ease-in-out forwards` : undefined
  </>
)
```

But I recommend you should:

- Create the CSS file then import it
- Toggle animation based on className will be better.

#### My solution

styles.css

```css
.modal__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

.modal__main {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  height: 80%;
  padding: 16px;
  bottom: -81%;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal__main-show {
  animation: SlideUp .5s ease-in-out forwards
}
.modal__main-hide {
  // or animation configs for slide out
  animation: none
}

@keyframes SlideUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-1%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-80%);
  }
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [isCheck, setIsCheck] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="js-modal__btn"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsCheck((prev) => !prev);
        }}
      >
        btn
      </div>
      <div className="modal__bg" />
      <div
        className={`modal__main ${
          isCheck ? "modal__main-show" : "modal__main-hide"
        }`}
      >
        <p>コンテンツ</p>

        <p className="js-modal__btn--close">close</p>
        <p className="js-modal__btn--close--fix"></p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I copied the code and tried to use it, but the background did not turn black.

Comment: @enoki: Because the css of modal__bg has `display: none`. You can add a class to toggle show/hide the background like the modal. Or just remove the display property then render `{isCheck && <div className="modal__bg" />}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isCheck` to show modal like this:

```
{isCheck && <div class="js-modal__main">...</div>}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bas-bf3zj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I enclosed it in isCheck, but it did not show up.